# Change VertexSize in ShowGraph from Combinatorica

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization, combinatorica

I am using `HasseDiagram` from Combinatorica (in 10.1). I am very happy to have found `HasseDiagram` because I am drawing Hasse diagrams. I also like that they are just black. However, I cannot access the vertex size. `ShowGraph` from Combinatorica only takes `VertexStyle` not `VertexSize` as an option and I don't get how to manipulate the size with this. `VertexStyle->Thick` does not do anything. Here is what I use:

```
ShowGraph[HasseDiagram@MakeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, #1 - #2 == 1 &],VertexStyle-> ?????]
```

Is there a way to make vertices thicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as in, e.g., `ListPlot`:

```
ShowGraph[HasseDiagram@MakeGraph[{1, 2, 3}, #1 - #2 == 1 &], 
 VertexStyle -> PointSize[0.1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The `ListPlot` reference might help me also in the future. It takes some experience to see through the different sets of available options for some graphics related commands. I get the feeling there are maybe two main classes but I haven't figured it out yet...